# valgrind help required

Tags: valgrind

My application is causing 10m of memory leak in one scenario. But when i debugged with valgrind, the following is the leak summary.

```
812 ==18074== LEAK SUMMARY:    
813 ==18074==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.    
814 ==18074==      possibly lost: 3,424 bytes in 20 blocks.   
815 ==18074==    still reachable: 10,422 bytes in 47 blocks.   
816 ==18074==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
```

what could i derive from this summary? can i say that there is no problem with application?

can somebody explain the following also? what could be the issue in creating thread? I am not even passing something dynamically allocated as thread argument.

```
795 ==18074== 2,448 bytes in 17 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 32 of 33  
796 ==18074==    at 0x40056BF: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:279)  
797 ==18074==    by 0xC0D71A: _dl_allocate_tls (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
798 ==18074==    by 0xD8A91E: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.1 (in /lib/tls/libpthread-2.3.4.so)  
799 ==18074==    by 0x8056A28: Server::intithreads() (ServerProcess.cpp:899)  
800 ==18074==    by 0x8054E39: main (ServerProcess.h:85)
```

Comment: are you using the pthread library in a C++ program?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry much about the "still reachable" blocks. Since all blocks are freed upon program exit, it isn't necessary to specifically free each block. To better the situation, you can try freeing blocks at intermediate stages in your program, beyond which you don't require them. On the other hand, "possibly lost" blocks are of slightly more serious nature.

In any case, from the [Valgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html):

> **"Still reachable"**. This covers cases
>   for the BBB blocks shown below. A
>   start-pointer or chain of
>   start-pointers to the block is found.
>   Since the block is still pointed at,
>   the programmer could, at least in
>   principle, have freed it before
>   program exit. Because these are very
>   common and arguably not a problem,
>   Memcheck won't report such blocks
>   individually unless
>   --show-reachable=yes is specified.

```
Pointer chain            
-------------            
RRR ------------> BBB    
RRR ---> AAA ---> BBB
```

> **"Possibly lost"**. This covers cases for
>   the BBB blocks shown below. This means
>   that a chain of one or more pointers
>   to the block has been found, but at
>   least one of the pointers is an
>   interior-pointer. This could just be a
>   random value in memory that happens to
>   point into a block, and so you
>   shouldn't consider this ok unless you
>   know you have interior-pointers.

```
Pointer chain            
-------------            
RRR ------?-----> BBB    
RRR ---> AAA -?-> BBB    
RRR -?-> AAA ---> BBB    
RRR -?-> AAA -?-> BBB
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be problems with your application according to the memory leak report.
If any of "definitely lost", "possibly lost" or "still reachable" are greater than 0, then you have a memory leak.

"Definitely lost" means that there was unfreed memory, and no variables pointing to it existed at program termination, because for example the variables went out of scope. This means that the leak will be difficult to fix, because you will need to find where you discarded them.

"Possibly lost" indicates that there was unfreed memory, and you *did* have variables pointing to it at program termination, but they were probably not usable to free the memory, because they were internal pointers, rather than pointers to the beginning of the block, which you need to pass to `free`.

"Still reachable" indicates that there was unfreed memory, but it was directly pointed to by variables at program termination. This means that although there is a leak, it is not one that can grow and so is not so serious.

Comment: do u mean to say that i will have to look into "Possibly lost" errors?

Comment: Yes, because they are the kind of leak that can grow.